# how to stop asyncatask from executing while checking not null in onpreexecute

Tags: android

I have this asynctask thats it working fine , however I want to check in `onPreExecute()` if the Edit text are empty or not before doing anything. this line `close();` is wrong I dont want edit text to be empty before connecting to server.

my other problem i want to add the alert dialog in `onPreExecute()` to tell the user to fill the empty edit text but                        `final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);` it will not be accessed in doInBackground , the image shows that its not being used but `alertdialogbuilder` exists in `doinbackground` how to make them access also there ?
[image]

```
  class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            name = usernam.getText().toString();
            pass = passw.getText().toString();
            //emails = email.getText().toString();
         if (name = null || pass =null)
            close(); // i guess this is wrong i want to stop the asynctask
            Log.e("GetText","called");

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           //doing connections to the server 


                       }else{
                       final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Wrong username or password, Try again please.");
                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the `EditText`s before you execute the `AsyncTask`? Also, `getText().toString()` will not return `null`. You want to check is it's empty.

Comment: set flag in onPreExecute and check this flag in doInBackground.If flat is set to false return null from doInBackground. 
`   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (running) {
            // does the hard work
        }
        return null;
    }
`

Comment: @MikeM. in several example I see they use `onPreExecute()` to define Edits texts. and how to check if its empty ?

Comment: @Rafal yes it might work this way, but i guess ill check them on `oncreate` what about the alertdialog how to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "define Edits texts", but why would you even want to start the `AsyncTask` if you don't have the necessary data? And by empty, I mean, e.g., `name.length() == 0` or `name.equals("")`.

Comment: Better approach will be check data first before running async task at all. 
onPreExecute was designed to notify UI that task was started, ex show dialog with progress, progress etc, not for validating data. Validation should be made before running async task

Comment: @MikeM. okay I will check the data first on `oncreate` but what about the alert dialog ? if i declare `final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new` on `oncreate` , i will have error on `alertDialogBuilder()` on doin background I add an image in my question.

Comment: @Rafal yes i will do the checking first , now for the alertdialog how should i fixe it.

Comment: alertdialogbuilde.build().show() ?

Comment: @Rafal no I get error cannot resolve `alertDialogBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `name` and `pass` will never be null where you are testing them (though they might be empty strings).

You cannot stop the AsyncTask once started - If you don't want the task executed, check the fields *before* you start the AsyncTask. If you must perform a test inside `onPreExecute`, just set a field to return from `doInBackground()` if you don't want it to do anything.

Lastly, you should show the AlertDialog in onPostExecute().

Something like this would be better:

```
void checkCredentials() {
   String name = usernam.getText().toString();
   String pass = passw.getText().toString();
          //emails = email.getText().toString();
   if (name.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
      showWrongCredentials();
   else
      new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute(name,pass);
}

void showWrongCredentials() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)....show();
}

class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
           String name = params[0];
           String pass = params[1];
           //doing connections to the server 
           ...
           // return true/false;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Boolean ok) {
           if (!ok)
             showWrongCredentials();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) the execution onPreExecute and check if canceled on doInBackground.